# Nested validation in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am a new in angular js. i have lost many times for preparing validation. many example has for total form validation. now i have to do the valid scope wise. I have shown my problem graphically below.

[image]

Here save yellow and red there are two portion, when i will click yellow save button then validation will be fire for red mark scope and when i will click red save button then validation will be fire for total page content. how can i solve this problem? can any one help me?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2tJxSh?p=preview)

Comment: @Vaibhav, see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/2tJxSh?p=preview

Comment: what kind of validation are we taking about?

Comment: @Vaibhav, do u have any nested form validation example in angularjs?,

Answer (score 0):

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation This link has validation for angularjs in a detailed manner with demo. Try replicating this. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/6H8Xx/2/ Try this aswell. Fiddle implemented with nested validation.

Comment: this is not helpful for me, you forgot my actual problem.