# Custom validation in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi All of the angular developer, I am fetching a validation problem with angular js. I can do the validation under the Form, I can check every validate field by Form in angular js. but i want to do the same job by using Div instead of Form. many people suggested me that you can do by angular directives. but how? They did not clear to me.Here how will i check all validate directives under the Div?. I have not found any solution. Anyone have an idea or solution?. I have given my example below. now i want to validate this by using angular js directives. Thanks

```
    <div name="userForm" novalidate>

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }">
            <label>Name*</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.username.$invalid && !userForm.username.$pristine }">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>

        <button type="button" ng-click="Save()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: try `ng-form` on the div

Comment: why would you care about using a form? is just a container you can style it as a div and keep the nice features that using forms in angular gives you

Comment: Hi, @Khanh TO can you give me a example? this will be very helpful to me. if you send a sample project. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi, @DayanMorenoLeon I have explained another question. please check my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014054/scope-validation-in-angular-js

Comment: so you have a problem with nested forms thats exactly what ng-form directive is for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm you can validate your child form and then check if the form is valid when validating the parent form as if the child form was another input field

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon yes you are right? is it possible?

Comment: yes you keep your child form as it is, and then on the parent form using the ng-submit for validation, you can check if your child form is valid, the forms status will be available to you as $scope.formname that will expose the object rewpresneting the status and information of your form :) just make sure you don't specify a controller in your child form so both parent and child can share scope

Comment: But i can not declare child form into parent form. nested form does not support in HTML5. how can i do now?

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-form:

```
 <div ng-form="userForm" novalidate>
  ...
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the instruction below

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation
http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesvalidation